# What does this interval mean?

Tags: calculus, statistics

First it says to choose the width *l* of the interval of points used to decided whether (t,y(t)) is an extreme.

Now later in the paper it says $y(t)$ is a local maximum only if

$$ \ y (t - j) < y(t) > y (t+ j) $$ for 0 < *j* < *l*

It seems this is not a method for finding local maximum in real time as they occur because 
you would only know if y(t) was a maximum for the interval 0 < *j* < *10* after the fact.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: That is a **definition** of "local maximum" not method for finding one.

Comment: So is there any method besides derivatives to find local maximum without it being in retro spec?